# My Captcha code is not working and it only shows a square thumbnail

Tags: php, mysql, captcha

My Captcha code is not working and it only shows a square thumbnail when i launch it on a browser can you spot the problem? i appreciate your help thanks

```
<?php 

session_start();
//Settings: You can customize the captcha here
$image_width = 120;
$image_height = 40;
$characters_on_image = 6;
$font = './monofont.ttf';

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid confusing characters (l 1 and i for example)
$possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ';
$random_dots = 0;
$random_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color="0x142864";
$captcha_noice_color = "0x142864";

$code = '';


$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
$code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
$i++;
}


$font_size = $image_height * 0.75;
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);


/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
        $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
        $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);


/* generating the dots randomly in background */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}


/* generating lines randomly in background of image */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height),
 mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
}


/* create a text box and add 6 letters code in it */
$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);


/* Show captcha image in the page html page */
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
imagejpeg($image);//showing the image
imagedestroy($image);//destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['6_letters_code'] = $code;

function hexrgb ($hexstr)
{
  $int = hexdec($hexstr);

  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
?>
```

My Captcha code is not working and it only shows a square thumbnail when i launch it on a browser can you spot the problem? i appreciate your help thanks,

[image]

Comment: According to your code, you have the actual captcha code in `captcha_code_file.php` file, so all the code you've posted so far is unrelated.

Comment: eis i've edited my question and put the captcha_code_file.php can you see whats the problem?

Comment: @JaycZeraval - what happens when you run that PHP code directly in your browser?

Comment: @andrewsi i've uploaded the image the captcha php codes wont generate any captcha images

Comment: @JaycZeraval - that wasn't what I asked. In your form, the captcha has an `<img src="your_php_file.php">`, right? What you need to do is open `your_php_file.php` in your browser, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have monofont.ttf in the same directory as your Captcha script location.  Please make sure it is there.

If you do not have that font file, I found this link after a quick Google search where you can download it. http://trac.assembla.com/webam/export/90/captcha/monofont.ttf

Download that file and place it in the same directory as your captcha php file.  I've tried it and it works correctly

[See a screenshot of it working on my sand box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBYzL.png)

Another possibility is that you don't have GD installed.  Dependent on your system, run:

Debian based system:

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```

Red-hat based:

```
yum installphp5-gd
```

might solve your problem as well.